# Soap Change Namespace prefix before send request

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

My soap envelope generated as following and i want to change generated ns1 for this tag `<ns1:RetrieveCustomer>` to be `<ns0:RetrieveCustomer>` :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security env:mustUnderstand="1"
            xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>pgw</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password
                    Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pgw</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:RetrieveCustomer soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
            xmlns:ns1="http://www.webmethods.com/MEAI_OnlineServices.webServices.PGW">
            <MSISDN xsi:type="xsd:string">123456789</MSISDN>
            <CustomerCode xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" />
        </ns1:RetrieveCustomer>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and i want to change this **ns1** to **ns0**:

```
<ns1:RetrieveCustomer soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                xmlns:ns1="http://www.webmethods.com/MEAI_OnlineServices.webServices.PGW">
                <MSISDN xsi:type="xsd:string">123456789</MSISDN>
                <CustomerCode xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" />
            </ns1:RetrieveCustomer>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this and what framework do you use to generate that SOAP request?

Comment: @AndreasVeithen i'm using Apache Axis , my problem that i generate this request to call a web service that return some data, but when i use the generated xml with **ns1** it's not working but when i changed it to **ns0** it's working fine.